# Saving excel worksheet to CSV with file name from a cell using a macro

Tags: vba, excel, csv

i have a macro that saves a copy of my workbook that works but it saves as a .xlsm
and i need it to be saved as a comma delimited .csv file type
can any one help me?

here is the macro i have now

> Sub toCSV()
>
> ```
> Dim newWB As Variant
> Dim wb1 As Workbook
> Set wb1 = ActiveWorkbook
> With wb1
>     .SaveCopyAs ("C:\Users\sales\desktop\") & Range("A2").Text & ".xlsm"
> End With
>
> End Sub
> ```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Code:

```
.SaveAs Filename:=("C:\Users\sales\desktop\") & Range("A2").Text & ".csv", _
FileFormat=:xlCSV
```

Comment: this works but i need to keep the current workbook open this leaves the original workbook and and goes to the saved one
i would like if passable to have a macro that saves a separate  copy of the workbook and keeps the original open

Comment: `.SaveCopyAs` does not support changing file type, so you can simply add a `Worksheet.Copy` with no parameters before the `.SaveAs` and change the `.SaveAs` to `ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:=("C:\Users\sales\desktop\") & wb1.Range("A2").Text & ".csv", _
FileFormat=:xlCSV` And then an `ActiveWorkbook.Close` after that.

Answer (score 2):

This code will take the sheet you want to be saved as a CSV, and copy it to a new workbook before saving

```
Dim CSVBook As Workbook
Set CSVBook = Workbooks.Add
ThisWorkbook.Sheets("TheCSVSheet").Copy Before:=CSVBook.Sheets(1)
CSVBook.SaveAs Filename:="C:\tmp\test.csv", FileFormat:=xlCSV
CSVBook.Close
```

This will allow you to save the file as a CSV, but still retain the original macro enabled spreadsheet which you can go back to, and do whatever other processing you need

Answer (score -1):

Try adding this to your code:

```
FileFormat:=xlCSVMSDOS
```

And changing the '.xlsm' to '.csv'

I also highly suggest you look [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff841185(v=office.15).aspx) for future questions with regard to saving!