# Export Excel to csv and deleting the last empty cells of a row

Tags: vba, excel, csv

I'm trying to write a Macro to export Excel to CSV but I'm very new in vba.
What I have now is :

```
Option Explicit

Sub ExportAsCSV()

    Dim MyFileName As String
    Dim CurrentWB As Workbook, TempWB As Workbook

    Set CurrentWB = ActiveWorkbook
    ActiveWorkbook.ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Copy

    Set TempWB = Application.Workbooks.Add(1)
    With TempWB.Sheets(1).Range("A1")
      .PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
      .PasteSpecial xlPasteFormats
    End With        

    Dim Change below to "- 4"  to become compatible with .xls files
    MyFileName = CurrentWB.Path & "\" & Left(CurrentWB.Name, Len(CurrentWB.Name) - 5) & ".csv"

    Application.DisplayAlerts = False
    TempWB.SaveAs Filename:=MyFileName, FileFormat:=xlCSV, CreateBackup:=False, Local:=True
    TempWB.Close SaveChanges:=False
    Application.DisplayAlerts = True
End Sub
```

from [Excel: macro to export worksheet as CSV file without leaving my current Excel sheet](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37037934/excel-macro-to-export-worksheet-as-csv-file-without-leaving-my-current-excel-sh)

Which is the correct csv but I'm trying to get rid of the extra ";" at the end of the rows. is there a way to do that please ?

Example:

```
1|2|3|4|5
2|5|3
2| |5
3
```

the export would give :

```
1;2;3;4;5
2;5;3;;
2;;5;;
3;;;;
```

What I want is :

```
1;2;3;4;5
2;5;3
2;;5
3
```

Is that possible ?

Thank you so much for your help

Edit:
Here is the code edited after the answer given :

```
Option Explicit
Public Function RemoveTrailing(s As String) As String
  Dim nIndex As Integer

  For nIndex = Len(s) To 1 Step -1
    If Right$(s, 1) = ";" Then
      s = Left$(s, Len(s) - 1)
    End If
  Next
  RemoveTrailing = s

End Function

Sub ExportAsCSV()

    Dim MyFileName As String
    Dim CurrentWB As Workbook, TempWB As Workbook

    Set CurrentWB = ActiveWorkbook
    ActiveWorkbook.ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Copy

    Set TempWB = Application.Workbooks.Add(1)
    With TempWB.Sheets(1).Range("A1")
        .PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
        .PasteSpecial xlPasteFormats
    End With

    'Dim Change below to "- 4"  to become compatible with .xls files
    MyFileName = CurrentWB.Path & "\" & Left(CurrentWB.Name, Len(CurrentWB.Name) - 5) & ".csv"

    Application.DisplayAlerts = False
    TempWB.SaveAs Filename:=MyFileName, FileFormat:=xlCSV, CreateBackup:=False, Local:=True
    TempWB.Close SaveChanges:=False
    Application.DisplayAlerts = True
    Dim sFile2 As String
      Dim sLine As String

      sFile2 = Replace(MyFileName, ".csv", "2.csv")
      Open MyFileName For Input As #1
      Open sFile2 For Output As #2

      Do Until EOF(1)
        Line Input #1, sLine
        Print #2, RemoveTrailing(sLine)
      Loop

      Close #1
      Close #2
End Sub
```

But I get an error "Incompatibility of types"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a function that will remove the trailing semi colons:

```
Public Function RemoveTrailing(s As String) As String
  Dim nIndex As Integer

  For nIndex = Len(s) To 1 Step -1
    If Right$(s, 1) = ";" Then
      s = Left$(s, Len(s) - 1)
    End If
  Next
  RemoveTrailing = s

End Function
```

Here's a much shorter code snippet that does the same thing:

```
Public Function RemoveTrailing2(s As String) As String
  Do Until Right$(s, 1) <> ";"
    s = Left$(s, Len(s) - 1)
  Loop
  RemoveTrailing2 = s
End Function
```

Here is how you use the above function. Basically what it does is read the CSV file line by line, and outputs each line to a new file that has stripped out the `;` characters. Add this to the very end of your routine:

```
  Dim sFile2 As String
  Dim sLine As String

  sFile2 = Replace(MyFilename, ".csv", "2.csv")
  Open MyFilename For Input As #1
  Open sFile2 For Output As #2

  Do Until EOF(1)
    Line Input #1, sLine
    Print #2, RemoveTrailing(sLine)
  Loop

  Close #1
  Close #2
```

The new file will have the same filename with a `2` at the end of the filename.

Comment: thank you for your answer, could you please tell me where I can use that exactly in the code ? ActiveWorkbook.ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Copy ?

Comment: I have added a short routine which uses the function to strip out the `;`.

Comment: I put the function just before the End sub but it doesn't work

Comment: Saying "it doesnt work" doesnt provide any information about what issue you are having. What is the error and on which line does the error occur?

Comment: when I don't put the function, the csv is generated with the extra ";" , however when I add the other, I have an error saying "the worksheet is already open" or "incompatible types" according to where I put the code

Comment: Small mistake on my part... I updated the line with `EOF` on it - Make that same change and try it.